# How can I solve this type error? TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#print first 3 similar games
i = 0
print('The 3 most recommended games to', name, 'are:\n')
for item in sorted_scores:
    game_name = steam_and_description_df[steam_and_description_df.game_id == item[0]]
    print(i+1, game_name)
    i = i + 1
    if i>2:
        break
```

Based on this code above, the type error happens on the game_name line code.

sorted_scores list

```
[(21872, 0.48374701837130774), (11515, 0.47249500411533485), (1623, 0.45933532497253254), (26951, 0.45573150915006005), (2929, 0.4544628310118689), (2902, 0.45233551503959735), (21275, 0.45160322552800564), (6485, 0.4494019003569672), (18721, 0.4493295836140727), (20464, 0.44814093729587356), (1326, 0.44558589411900384), (3554, 0.44528310669254334), (484, 0.44317385265582554), (9862, 0.44190961366257975), (20380, 0.43996794991372373), (14599, 0.4373114243610174), (4955, 0.4328844472660066), (6472, 0.43171551382770684), (7126, 0.42777317464066944), (22454, 0.4271522829155004), (3410, 0.4269326251274042), (21182, 0.42652921604328786), (171, 0.42589781096171214), (3736, 0.42550532908850214), (15114, 0.4254465291937926), (13544, 0.42510317971074085), (24987, 0.42421505708449514), (1273, 0.42410801324765734), (163, 0.4240960994393835), (23955, 0.42266514977135616), (6419, 0.42263696226704894), (21864, 0.42206485242778047), (14483, 0.4220267461087165), (22450, 0.4219432263130382), (1105, 0.4218351111835161), (7264, 0.4209821886577657), (23887, 0.42031314624465277), (1332, 0.4198645242324752), (11104, 0.4190435412010168), (4274, 0.4188913814114361), (6666, 0.4173564041086213), (3693, 0.4169652359763997), (26532, 0.41676410953682813), (13139, 0.4167345511816124), (67, 0.41661513252335747), (203, 0.4165230768457668), (9900, 0.41631620346038), (4751, 0.41565474657798546), (8114, 0.41532313839884144), (5486, 0.4152042025242376), (6210, 0.41483481695494123), (3103, 0.4148085045905877), (1302, 0.4134559224189003), (3786, 0.4132979814795533), (23044, 0.41292733275039506), (23355, 0.41287001789524513), (7180, 0.41260035566948594), (10812, 0.4120026522918673), (11380, 0.4119672651150211), (7670, 0.41117173731206785), (5475, 0.411152392221655), (20424, 0.4110941833132201), (181, 0.41104596767039664), (546, 0.4109425554675847), (26332, 0.4107069175381574), (24497, 0.4106471108195314), (15343, 0.41039264541262993), (6616, 0.41021959487753734), (17525, 0.41018356961981745), (468, 0.4100760790091801), (16841, 0.4095624265040569), (323, 0.4092635136710355), (4557, 0.40926027763932415), (17387, 0.4086626969030762), (14020, 0.40858112510204303), (20405, 0.4084553567203099), (3309, 0.4082852543256077), (8553, 0.40792385647413887), (5761, 0.4076134079818193), (6691, 0.40756899755410925), (13015, 0.40742987396782426), (16957, 0.4072474698274307), (6496, 0.40723509023947496), (14490, 0.40723421075461286), (22594, 0.406900750002858), (5045, 0.40680892161821663), (9369, 0.4068074601386988), (25087, 0.4067326285437382), (17831, 0.40670102913556055), (26686, 0.40637645361791325), (6538, 0.4063239547842654), (14571, 0.40619269023079585), (68, 0.406117601970229), (3064, 0.4060045145683347), (5473, 0.4059997859889778), (16325, 0.4058424434593101), (1745, 0.40507204835014066), (2648, 0.4048289434390435), (7621, 0.40479908558274), (13822, 0.4046610288469533), (1567, 0.40434533764564856), (17462, 0.40429924058938455), (12, 0.40411096047206324), (3393, 0.40378838495442265), (3411, 0.4037237132151256), (9459, 0.40343927554580583), (7612, 0.4033783257323473), (14347, 0.40336523716313777), (5883, 0.40334055350510595), (341, 0.403112882335462), (16107, 0.4029710672302373), (969, 0.4029125606171325), (13993, 0.4028770063296113), (10838, 0.40273594501573884), (337, 0.4021402455525484), (1647, 0.40204130966736273), (1772, 0.40202933848594846), (24925, 0.40192516933477057), (2210, 0.4018133457268974), (7095, 0.40172002062379053), (4571, 0.4013939824743619), (1600, 0.4013353930081608), (13042, 0.400942794025819), (3305, 0.40077993885007746), (5644, 0.40077818091759665), (11550, 0.40045672493308887), (11793, 0.4002455405195208), (8667, 0.3999426462344592), (16093, 0.39989902520871207), (24862, 0.3998022852793553), (20127, 0.39977101947046867), (19, 0.39970794535495846), (25378, 0.39970493967252374), (2188, 0.39964035657249763), (15035, 0.3992037436389809), (22571, 0.39889399191574326), (13593, 0.39879124518530507), (8668, 0.39878498285678204), (26023, 0.39877225238734504), (9282, 0.39876658963208456), (18523, 0.3987487001758809), (10038, 0.39847931287981736), (3634, 0.39810422926320993)]
```

steam_and_description_df

```
steam_appid name    release_date    english developer   publisher   platforms   required_age    categories  genres  ... negative_ratings    average_playtime    median_playtime owners  price   detailed_description    about_the_game  short_description   game_id important_features
0   10  Counter-Strike  2000-11-01  1   Valve   Valve   windows;mac;linux   0   Multi-player;Online Multi-Player;Local Multi-P...   Action  ... 3339    17612   317 10000000-20000000   7.19    Play the world's number 1 online action game. ...   Play the world's number 1 online action game. ...   Play the world's number 1 online action game. ...   0   Counter-Strike Valve Valve Multi-player;Online...
1   20  Team Fortress Classic   1999-04-01  1   Valve   Valve   windows;mac;linux   0   Multi-player;Online Multi-Player;Local Multi-P...   Action  ... 633 277 62  5000000-10000000    3.99    One of the most popular online action games of...   One of the most popular online action games of...   One of the most popular online action games of...   1   Team Fortress Classic Valve Valve Multi-player...
```

I got this as output

```
The 3 most recommended games to Counter-Strike are:

       steam_appid                                       name release_date  \
20611       807730  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2018   2018-03-13   

       english          developer          publisher platforms  required_age  \
20611        1  Wolverine Studios  Wolverine Studios   windows             0   

          categories                            genres  ... negative_ratings  \
20611  Single-player  Indie;Simulation;Sports;Strategy  ...                3   

       average_playtime  median_playtime   owners  price  \
20611                 0                0  0-20000  11.39   

                                    detailed_description  \
20611  Take control as head coach of your favorite co...   

                                          about_the_game  \
20611  Take control as head coach of your favorite co...   

                                       short_description game_id  \
20611  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2018 puts...   20611   

                                      important_features  
20611  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2018 Wolv...  

[1 rows x 23 columns]
       steam_appid                                       name release_date  \
17896       729310  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2017   2017-11-14   

       english          developer          publisher platforms  required_age  \
17896        1  Wolverine Studios  Wolverine Studios   windows             0   

                              categories                            genres  \
17896  Single-player;Shared/Split Screen  Indie;Simulation;Sports;Strategy   

       ... negative_ratings  average_playtime  median_playtime   owners  \
17896  ...                4                 0                0  0-20000   

       price                               detailed_description  \
17896   3.99  Take control as head coach of your favorite co...   

                                          about_the_game  \
17896  Take control as head coach of your favorite co...   

                                       short_description game_id  \
17896  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2017 puts...   17896   

                                      important_features  
17896  Draft Day Sports: College Basketball 2017 Wolv...  

[1 rows x 23 columns]
       steam_appid               name release_date  english  \
16283       683600  Football Mogul 18   2017-09-19        1   

                developer           publisher platforms  required_age  \
16283  Sports Mogul, Inc.  Sports Mogul, Inc.   windows             0   

                                              categories  \
16283  Single-player;Shared/Split Screen;Steam Achiev...   

                                  genres  ... negative_ratings  \
16283  Casual;Simulation;Sports;Strategy  ...               10   

       average_playtime  median_playtime       owners  price  \
16283                 0                0  20000-50000   5.79   

                                    detailed_description  \
16283  <strong><i>Football Mogul®</i></strong> begins...   

                                          about_the_game  \
16283  <strong><i>Football Mogul®</i></strong> begins...   

                                       short_description game_id  \
16283  Football Mogul 18 is the 16th version of the a...   16283   

                                      important_features  
16283  Football Mogul 18 Sports Mogul, Inc. Sports Mo...  

[1 rows x 23 columns]
In [120]:

1
```

But I would like to only show the name is it possible? How can i Do so, i am just making more word counts.
It shows all the columns but I want to show merely the name of the game is it possible in this code?

Comment: The error lies in ```item[0]['name'].values[0]]``` . Here you are trying to take data from the tuple and not the dataframe where 'name' column doesnt exist and that is why it is throwing the error. Use ```item[0]``` instead.

Comment: For `item[0]['name']`, `item[0]` is a integer , not subsscriptable.

Comment: Use double tuple unpacking

Comment: @HarrisMinhas I used item[0] but error comes out
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Jason Yang so I must change the data type of int to string?
what is double tuple packaing?

Comment: Dont use ```item[0].values[0]]``` . Use only ```item[0]```

Comment: the `item` from `sorted_scores` has no `name` and `values`,the item is tuple datatype.maybe you want `item[0]` as `21872` or `item[1]` as `0.48374701837130774`

Comment: @HarrisMinhas ok. I use item[0] but i don't get the name of the game

Comment: Thats because the name of the game corresponding to the game_id doesnt exists in your dataframe.

Comment: For example, your first `item` is `(21872, 0.48374701837130774)`,  `item[0]` will be `21872`.  In your code didn't show any variable with attribute `['name'].values[0]`, and it looks like your `game_id` is `0 or 1`, so no suggestion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for your task,

```
#print first 3 similar games
i = 0
print('The 3 most recommended games to', name, 'are:\n')
for item in sorted_scores:
    game_name = steam_and_description_df.loc[(steam_and_description_df.game_id == item[0]),['name']]
    print(i+1, game_name)
    i = i + 1
    if i>2:
        break
```

Comment: Hi Harris Minhas thank you for your answer but I do not get the name of the game

Comment: You will only get the name of the game if it corresponds with the game_id that we are providing it with from the sorted_scores list.

Comment: Hello. Yes I have edited my question to show the output but I get a whole list instead of the name of the game..

Comment: The reason that is happening could be that there are more than one games corresponding to each game_id in your dataframe. You should try to clean the data in the dataframe before trying to fetch specific data from it.

Comment: no i get the whole row of data corresponding to the id but I only want the name column

Comment: `print(i+1, game_name.name)` ?

Comment: @fyceheist I have made some modifications to the code, this will solve your problem.